# Kurt Kinetic SDK Integration in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have integrated Kinetic SDK in iOS and verified authorization status.

```
[KineticSDK launch:@"api key"];

    if ([KineticSDK status] == KineticAPIStatusUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"KineticAPIStatusUnknown");
    }else if ([KineticSDK status] == KineticAPIStatusAuthorized){
        NSLog(@"KineticAPIStatusAuthorized");
    }else if ([KineticSDK status] == KineticAPIStatusRejected){
        NSLog(@"KineticAPIStatusRejected");
    }
```

But we are not able to get data using `processConfigurationData` and `processPowerData` methods. 
Here what should we use key for Power Service Config Characteristic and systemId.

Comment: did you add you API key in [KineticSDK launch:@"api key"];

Comment: Yes i have added API key.